# Error in JGROUPs for EhCache, drop message sender not in table

Tags: java, hibernate, wildfly, ehcache, jgroups

I have four nodes in a cluster, and I need synchronize them. When node BRJGSD309173 tried send a messages through JGROUPs to BRJGSD333007, the server BRJGSD333007 informed the message below:

> 11:34:07,759 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK] (Incoming-2,maestroCacheManager,BRJGSD333007-24075) BRJGSD333007-24075: dropped message 4787 from BRJGSD309173-7667 (sender not in table [BRJGSD333007-24075]), view=[BRJGSD333007-24075|0] [BRJGSD333007-24075]

The follow configuration of eh jgroups_tcp.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
 <config>
     <TCP bind_port="7800" 
          max_bundle_size="5M" />
     <TCPPING timeout="3000"
              initial_hosts="brjgsm10.weg.net[7800],brjgsm11.weg.net[7800],brjgsd309173.weg.net[7800],brjgsd333007.weg.net[7800]"
              port_range="10"
              num_initial_members="5"/>
     <VERIFY_SUSPECT timeout="1500"  />
     <pbcast.NAKACK use_mcast_xmit="false"
                    retransmit_timeout="300,600,1200,2400,4800"
                discard_delivered_msgs="true"/>
     <pbcast.STABLE stability_delay="1000" desired_avg_gossip="50000" max_bytes="400000"/>
     <pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="true" join_timeout="5000" view_bundling="true"/>
 </config>
```

And a fragment of ehcache.xml

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    updateCheck="false" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" name="maestroCacheManager">
...
    <cache 
        name="objectServiceExecute"
        maxEntriesLocalHeap="100000" 
        eternal="false" >
        <cacheEventListenerFactory
              class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jgroups.JGroupsCacheReplicatorFactory"
              properties="replicateAsynchronously=true, replicatePuts=true,
              replicateUpdates=true, replicateUpdatesViaCopy=true, replicateRemovals=true" />
    </cache>

    <diskStore 
        path="java.io.tmpdir/ehcache" />

    <cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jgroups.JGroupsCacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
        properties="file=jgroups_tcp.xml"
        propertySeparator=";" 
    /> 

    <cache 
        name="org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache" 
        maxElementsInMemory="10000000" 
        eternal="true" 
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />

    <defaultCache 
        maxElementsInMemory="10000000" 
        eternal="true"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" >
        <cacheEventListenerFactory
              class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jgroups.JGroupsCacheReplicatorFactory"
              properties="replicateAsynchronously=true, replicatePuts=true,
              replicateUpdates=true, replicateUpdatesViaCopy=true, replicateRemovals=true" />
    </defaultCache>

</ehcache>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very stange JGroups configuration! You're missing failure detection protocols, `UNICAST3` and `MERFGE3` etc!

The error above means that you received a message from a member not in the cluster, so it was consequently dropped. Why the member was not in the cluster is unclear, perhaps it didn't join correctly. Since you *don't* have any failure detection protocols, it can't have been suspected and expelled.

I suggest copy `tcp.xml` shipped with JGroups and replace `TCPPING` with your `TCPPING` config. Also make sure you set `bind_addr` in `TCP`, to make sure JGroups binds to the correct interface.

Hope this helps, 
Cheers